# How to decompile python ELF file (Compiled with Nuitka)?

Tags: decompilation, gdb, python

I have some files that compiled with [nuitka](https://github.com/Nuitka/Nuitka). formats are **.bin**. I could get shell access to running process with pyrasite same as [this guide](https://gist.github.com/simonw/8aa492e59265c1a021f5c5618f9e6b12). but I cannot decompile function codes or anything else, and also tried [unpyc37](https://github.com/andrew-tavera/unpyc37/).

shell access to process is all I have. I can print variables and see values but how can I access functions code ?
or is there another way to extract codes ?
[image]

Comment: Nuitka compiles the Python code directly to assembly. Unpyc37 and similar decompilers work on the Python bytecode and there isn't any in a nuitka binary.

Comment: Its hard to read assembly codes that made by nuitka. its all python default codes in it. is there easy way to read this assembly codes ? i tried ghidra its so hard.